# Checking ERC721 token approvals in a for loop works in Hardhat Script but fails in React

Tags: metamask, hardhat, erc-721, react, hardhat-deploy

Here is my function, event and modifier:

```
event TransferComplete();     

modifier isApproved(address[] memory contractArr) {
    require(contractArr.length > 0, "Length Zero");
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < contractArr.length; i++) {
        address currAddr = contractArr[i];
        require(currAddr != zero, "Contract address is ZERO");
        bool isApproved = IERC721(currAddr).isApprovedForAll(_msgSender(), address(this));
        require(isApproved == true, "Not Approved");
    }
    _;
}
```

```
function sendTokens(address[] memory contractAddrs, uint256[] memory tokenIds, address otherAddress) external isApproved(contractAddrs) {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < contractAddrs.length; i++) {
        IERC721 tokenContract = IERC721(contractAddrs[i]);
        tokenContract.safeTransferFrom(_msgSender(), otherAddress, tokenIds[i]);
    } 
    emit TransferComplete;
}
```

The `sendTokens` function has `isApproved` modifier which checks if the `contractAddrs` being passed have approved my contract for transferring their ERC721 tokens. I setup a hardhat deploy script which deploys this contract on my hardhat node with mainnet fork, sets approvals for a NFT contract address, and then calls `sendTokens` function with approved contract address and a token ID. Everything works as expected and and I see the `TransferComplete` event in my transaction receipt.

The problem is that when I call the same `sendTokens` function from my React frontend using metamask, the transaction fails with a couple of different reasons. Console logs show that execution reverts on the `IERC721(currAddr).isApprovedForAll` line in the modifier during the first loop.

Most times the error is

```
Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string
```

But sometimes its also

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function
```

I have double checked everything and tried various things but none worked. Here is what I tried which didn't work:

```
Verify if the ABI and Bytecode being generated by Hardhat runtime environment during deployment match the ones I'm importing in React frontend.
Set manual gasLimits
Use Ganache or Anvil instead of Hardhat node
Use Frame and Brave wallets to make sure its not a metamask issue
Verify that ethers version being used by Hardhat runtime environment is the same being used on the frontend
Deployed on Goerli, same results -> HRE function call succeeds but React one fails
```

Any insights would be helpful and appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I was passing an incorrect address from UI but passing the correct address in the Hardhat script. Since the address being passed wasn't an ERC721 contract, the transaction was failing.